# MaterializeCSS Collapsible onOpen change Icon of header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

I'm trying to change the icon of toggled collapsible I don't understand how to perform this trigger according to their documents.

```
$('.collaps_roles_permission').collapsible({
    accordion: true,    
    onOpen: function(el){
        //$('li.roles_icon', this).html('remove');
        console.log(el);
        console.log(el[0]);
    },
    onClose:function(el){
        //switch back icon to normal
    }

});
```

How can I change collapsible header when it toggled?

```
<div class="collapsible-header">
    <i class="material-icons roles_icon">add</i>
    {{ $r->display_name }}
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add demo link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your `onOpen` function, use `el` to find the icon in the header.

```
onOpen: function(el) {
    $(el).find('.collapsible-header i').text('remove');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simply using .click event of jQuery:

```
$('.collapsible').click(function() {
    $(this).collapsible({
        onOpen: function(el) { el.find('.collapsible-header').text('Changed'); }
    });
});
```